# Export QlikSense application (QVF) file to a PRJ folder

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

In QlikView whenever we create any -prj folder on same directory where QVW files resides, when we save QVW it automatically creates xml/text files under prj folder.

It really helps in version controlling of changes but when it comes to QlikSense(QVF) I dont see that option working anymore.

Please suggest how can we create xml/txt files from QVF

Comment: Apparently there is no such feature in Qlik Sense, just an extension. See more in this thread in the Qlik Community:

https://community.qlik.com/t5/New-to-Qlik-Sense/PRJ-and-version-controlling-in-Qliksense/td-p/1385918

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no PRJ/XML option in Qlik Sense, however you can "unbuild" an app into all the relevant JSON objects which is very similar. You can read about it on the relevant help page on qlik.dev: https://qlik.dev/toolkits/qlik-cli/app/app-unbuild/. It's worth noting that this warns that it's an experimental command when you run it, although this is not noted in the documentation.

For example:
`qlik app unbuild --app dab6a3f2-5ae1-420c-9cda-dbb6c618ac77 --dir unbuiltapp`

This will create a folder called unbuiltapp and in there will be:

- An objects folder with one JSON file per UI object and some other bits like derived calendar fields
- app-properties.json - the overall App properties
- config.yml (Note this is YAML not JSON)
- connections.yml (Note this is YAML not JSON)
- dimensions.json - the Master Dimensions
- measures.json - the Master Measures
- script.qvs - the data load script
- variables.json - the variables